# Gradle build multi modules project with transitive dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I have problem with building my simple app. It contains 3 modules, ejb, rest and ear in which rest should be included. To achieve it I wrote build.gradle as one below. But I still have problems. Built ear looks like:

```
ear-1.0.ear
|--ejbs-1.0.jar
|--rest-1.0.jar
|--lib
   |--ejbs-1.0.jar
   |--other libs..
```

As you can see, I have here duplicated `ejbs-1.0.jar`. It's no something I want so I have tried to work this around. I have tried 2 approaches I found on web but neither of them worked. First one (comments with label 1) excluded all `rest` dependencies from going into lib dir. Second (label 2) did the same but also included `rest-1.0.jar` into lib, making it even worse.
Now I have no idea how to write my `build.gradle` so it puts jars made from subprojects in root dir, and their dependencies in lib dir. I have also tried to write something like comments with label 3, but this makes script fail.  Is there easy way to excluded it like that with similar syntax?

```
project(":ejbs") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.2'
    }
}

project(":rest") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {

        compile project(':ejbs')
        compile group: 'javax.ejb', name: 'javax.ejb-api', version: '3.2'
        compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'jsr311-api', version: '0.11'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.2'
    }
}

project(":ear") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "ear"

    dependencies {
        //1: def nonTransitive = {transitive = false}
        deploy project(":ejbs")
        deploy project(":rest")
        earlib project(path:":ejbs", configuration:"compile")
        earlib project(path:":rest", configuration:"compile")//1: , nonTransitive
        //2: add('earlib', project(':rest')) {
        //    transitive = false
        //}
        //3: earlib project(path:":rest", configuration:"compile") {
        //    exlude project(':ejbs')
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `exclude module: 'ejbs'` instead of `exclude project ':ejbs'`?

Comment: No matter if I use exclude project or module. I still gets following exception. `Could not find method exlude() for arguments [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ProjectBackedModule@4006c95c] on DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':rest'', configuration='default'}.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I made it this way:

```
project(":ear") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "ear"

    dependencies {
        deploy project(":ejbs")
        deploy project(":rest")
        earlib project(path:":ejbs", configuration:"compile")
        earlib(project(path:":rest", configuration:"compile")) {
            exclude module: 'ejbs'
        }
    }
}
```